# Pushing a different set of files to different repositories

Tags: git, github

I have a web app on Heroku that contains a configuration file with database login information.

I want to push this project to Github as well, but without the configuration file.

Making a new commit without that file would remove it from the HEAD, but it'd still be there in the previous commits, I don't want this file on Github in the first place.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can find your answer to your question there : [removing a file from every commit](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html#removing_a_file_from_every_commit)

Comment: I'll have to create a new branch and apply this to it, right?

Comment: push -f or a new branch. As you want.

Comment: If I apply this to master, the app won't work on Heroku, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `git filter-branch`. I would use the index filter as it's faster due to not having to checkout each commit to do it's job.